# AngularJS, angular.element($0).scope() reveals functions from every controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When trying to use

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

in the browser console, I found that each element's scope has each function from EVERY controller as a property. 
For example

```
<body ng-app = "app">
      <div ng-controller="VideoController">Inspect Me</div>
      <div ng-controller = "DocumentController">Inspect Me</div>
</body>
```

Then inspecting the DocumentController div will reveal functions like playVideo or pauseVideo, which only exist in VideoController

This remains true when clicking inspecting body which just has ng-app="app" on it. Isn't this exactly what shouldn't be happening with controllers?

If this is a bug in my code, how would I step through it?

Comment: In general you should provide code to associate with your question, please provide code for setting up a controller in your app for reference

Answer (score 0):

`$0` is a variable injected by Chrome. Depending on where it sits in your `Elements` tab of Chrome depicts what value it will have. This will determine what your `scope()` return will be.